# Kernel of an homomorphism between two free groups

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, free-groups

I am trying to prove that $G=\langle \alpha,\beta,\gamma \mid \alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}\beta^{-1}\gamma \rangle$ is isomorphic to $H=\langle \delta,\varepsilon \mid \hspace{0.5cm}\rangle$. Let N be the smallest normal subgroup including $\alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}\beta^{-1}\gamma$

In order to prove it, I define a surjective map from $\langle \alpha,\beta,\gamma\rangle$ to $\langle \delta,\varepsilon\rangle$ and I try to apply the First Isomorphism Theorem.

$\varphi:\langle \alpha,\beta,\gamma\rangle \longrightarrow \langle \delta,\varepsilon\rangle$ with $\varphi(\alpha)=\delta,\varphi(\beta)=\varepsilon,\varphi(\gamma)=\varepsilon\delta\varepsilon^{-1}\delta^{-1}$. $\varphi$ is clearly surjective and $\varphi(\alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}\beta^{-1}\gamma)=\delta\varepsilon\delta^{-1}\varepsilon^{-1}\varepsilon\delta\varepsilon^{-1}\delta^{-1}=e$. So $N\subset\text{Ker}(\varphi)$

How do I prove $\text{Ker}(\varphi)\subset N$?

Comment: I have edited the post and called the two groups $G$ and $H$. It is straightforward to check that the homomorphism $\psi:H \to G$ with $\psi(\delta)=\alpha$, $\psi(\epsilon)=\beta$ is a $2$-sided inverse to $\varphi$, so both maps are isomorphisms.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit informaly, you could not that the only relation is the one that says $\gamma=\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}\alpha^{-1}$. This relation is just saying that $\gamma$ can be obtained from $\alpha$ and $\beta$, so you can eliminate $\gamma$ together with this relation. Since no other relations are presented, the result is $\langle\alpha,\beta|\ \rangle$.